# VBA querytables loop placing retrieved data in not correct cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a little macro to retrieve data from a website that has the table in rows of 30.

The problem is that when I loop, every iteration of the loop places data to the column at the right instead of below. I mean, my query retrieves data from Columns A to Q until row 30. When I get the next iteration I would want that it gets Columns A to Q but from row 31 to 61.

Thing is it places from Columns R to... XX until row 30.
I guess the issue might be on the Destination:=Range...

```
Sub Extract_data_table()
'
' Extract_data_table Macro


' For i = 1 to 41
For x = 1 To 41
Z = (x * 30) - 29
Worksheets("NHL_results_RS").Select
Worksheets("NHL_results_RS").Activate
mystr = "URL;http://www.nhl.com/stats/game?fetchKey=20062ALLSATALL&viewName=summary&sort=gameDate&gp=1&pg=" & x

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    **mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))**
    '.CommandType = 0
    .Name = _
    "game?fetchKey=20062ALLSATALL&viewName=summary&sort=gameDate&gp=1&pg=1_2"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "3"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Next x

End Sub
```

Could any of you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in assuming the problem lies in `Destination`. I have never used this command, but after some brief experimenting I've deducted that if the `Destination` is occupied, it will paste the data in the nearest suitable space to the **right** of your original destination.

To bypass this, you should add an `Offset` to your destination range, based on your iterator, which is `x` in your example.

What I did was this:

```
Destination:=Range("$A$1").Offset((x - 1) * 31, 0))
```

This would work, but you'll notice that you will be repeating the column headers, so I guess you'll need to experiment with `.FieldNames` a bit as well.